# Multidimensional Parallel Coordinates Plot in LaTex

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot, parallel

I'm new to LaTex and trying to import Parallel Coordinates Plots which I created in [Matlab](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/parallelplot.html). There are up to 16 variables and 1000 data entries. Also I need different plots with different variables. I exported my data from Matlab as a .csv file, but I was only able to reproduce the Plot with a Matlab Tool called [matlab2tikz](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22022-matlab2tikz-matlab2tikz). But it hardcodes the values in the LaTex Code. I would rather use an external file with only the data. Is there an elegant way to do this?

Comment: You can plot data in LaTeX using Pgfplots from an external file. Check this post (section: Plot data from a multicolumn file in LaTeX): 
https://latexdraw.com/plot-a-function-and-data-in-latex/#t-1609877459797

Comment: Yeah I know that. But I need a large amount of lines in that Plot. And it would be great, if it works with any .csv file I use. So it should read the VariableNames and label them and so on.

Comment: So you mean that everything should be done automatically? You select an input csv file and LaTeX reads how many columns it has, loads them in PGFPlofs and then also writes their corresponding legend (I guess the column name). If that is right, I think you could adapt the code that @LateXdraw-com wrote with a `foreach` loop.

Comment: You are right, a foreach loop should work. But I haven't figured out how to extract the table headers to use them as labels for the x-axis. Do you know how that's done?